# How do I programmatically install Maven libraries to a cluster using init scripts?

Tags: maven, cluster-computing, databricks, azure-databricks

Have been trying for a while now and Im sure the solution is simple enough, just struggling to find it. Im pretty new so be easy on me..!

Its a requirement to do this using a premade init-script, which is then selected in the UI when configuring the cluster.

I am trying to install `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.18` to a cluster on Azure Databricks. Following the documentations example (it is installing a postgresql driver) they produce an init script using the following command:

````py
dbutils.fs.put("/databricks/scripts/postgresql-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
wget --quiet -O /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/postgresql-42.2.2.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.2/postgresql-42.2.2.jar""", True)```
````

My question is, what is the `/mnt/driver-daemon/jars/postgresql-42.2.2.jar` section of this code? And what would I have to do to make this work for my situation?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/mnt/driver-daemon/jars/postgresql-42.2.2.jar` here is the output path where the jar file will be put.  But it makes no sense as this jar won't be put into CLASSPATH and won't be found by Spark.  Jars need to be put into `/databricks/jars/` directory, where they will be picked up by Spark automatically.

But this method with downloading of jars works only for jars without dependencies, and for libraries like EventHubs connector this is not a case - they won't work if dependencies aren't downloaded as well.  Instead it's better to use [Cluster UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/cluster-libraries#cluster-installed-library) or Libraries API (or Jobs API for jobs) - with these methods, all dependencies will be fetched as well.

P.S. But really, instead of using EventHubs connector, it's better to use Kafka protocol that is supported by EventHubs as well. There are several reasons for that:

- It's better from performance standpoint
- It's better from stability standpoint
- Kafka connector is included into DBR, so you don't need to install anything extra

You can read how to use Spark + EventHubs + Kafka connector in the [EventHubs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-kafka-spark-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks Alex, its appreciated.